# Dynamically update GridView results based on text entered into a textbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I would like to dynamically update the results of a GridView based on characters that are entered into a textbox.  My code currently works but only fires the update when the textbox loses focus or the user tabs out of the textbox.  AutoPost is set to true for the textbox.  I have the code to refresh the SQLDataSource, I just want the update to happen as the user enters characters in the textbox.  I imagine this will require client side action, but not sure where to start.  Thank you.

### MARKUP

```
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" ViewStateMode="Enabled"></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" />

      <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="NameFirst" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="NameFirst" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="NameLast" HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="NameLast" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="State_ID" HeaderText="State" SortExpression="State_ID" />
        </Columns>
      </asp:GridView>
```

### CODEBEHIND

```
Protected Sub txtSearch_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtSearch.TextChanged
GridData()
End Sub

Private Sub GridData()
    Dim conString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyConnectionString").ToString()
    Dim sqlcon As New SqlConnection(conString)
    Dim sqlcmd As SqlCommand
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable()
    Dim query As [String]

    If txtsearch.Text = "" Then
      query = "SELECT [Individual_ID], [NameFirst], [NameLast], [Address], [City], [State_ID], [ZipCode], [Comment] FROM [t_Individual] ORDER BY [NameLast], [NameFirst]"
    Else
      query = "SELECT [Individual_ID], [NameFirst], [NameLast], [Address], [City], [State_ID], [ZipCode], [Comment] FROM [t_Individual] WHERE [NameLast] LIKE N'%" + txtSearch.Text + "%' ORDER BY [NameLast], [NameFirst]"
    End If
    sqlcmd = New SqlCommand(query, sqlcon)
    sqlcon.Open()
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd)
    dt.Clear()
    da.Fill(dt)
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
      GridView1.DataSourceID = ""
      GridView1.DataSource = dt
      GridView1.DataBind()
    Else
      GridView1.DataBind()
    End If
    sqlcon.Close()
  End Sub
```

Comment: This may help you to do the client part: http://www.loadx.org/filter-gridview-as-you-type-asp-net-c-with-jquery/

Comment: Thank you Ali, I just looked at the info in the link and I'm excited to try this approach.  I'll report back my results.